# How to localize text in asp.net.core Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I can't find any examples on how to localize text within a C# asp.net.core application.  I would appreciate any help.

I'm assuming that I need to use StringLocalizaer somehow.

Thanks

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
//using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;

namespace NotificationSystem.Models
{
    public class GroupList : List<Group>
    {
        public GroupList()
        {
            LoadGroupTypes();
        }

        protected List<Group> _Groups { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> GroupTypes { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> LoadGroupTypes()
        {
            // ToDo: Implement other GroupTypes / DB Settings pull 
            GroupTypes = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "USER-STATIC",
                    Value = "Users List - Static"  // ToDo: Globalize
                }
            };

            return GroupTypes;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these texts coming from DB or hard coded in the cs file?

Comment: Hard-coded in the .cs file.

Comment: There is no way to add it to a Model, except if you're gonna instantiate the model with injected service every time.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly think that it is necessary to use

> Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;

 namespace Localization.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AboutController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<AboutController> _localizer;

    public AboutController(IStringLocalizer<AboutController>  localizer) // use dependency injector
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return _localizer["About Title"];
    }
}
}
```

You can use this code before writing the key-value to the resource file

All information is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Add dictonary in resource is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#resource-files)

Comment: But I'm in a Model, not a Controller.  I found the Controller examples, but I couldn't figure out how to apply that in my model.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to localize these values in the view, just like any other text localization:

```html
@inject IStringLocalizer _localizer;

<select ..>
    @foreach(var item in Model.GroupList)
    {
        <option value="@_localizer[item.Value]">@_localizer[item.Text]</option>
    }
</select>
```

Another way is to instantiate the model with `IStringLocalizer` in constructor:

```cs
public class GroupList : List<Group>
{
    private readonly IStringLocaizer _localizer;

    public GroupList(IStringLocalizer localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
        LoadGroupTypes();
    }

    // ...

    public List<SelectListItem> LoadGroupTypes()
    {
        // ToDo: Implement other GroupTypes / DB Settings pull 
        GroupTypes = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = _localizer["USER-STATIC"],
                Value = _localizer["Users List - Static"]  // ToDo: Globalize
            }
        };

        return GroupTypes;
    }
}
```

Then you have to pass an instance of `IStringLocalizer` while creating the model:

```cs
public HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;
    public HomeController(IStringLocalizer localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // ...
        var groupList = new GroupList(_localizer);
    }
}
```